# Copy specific cell to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

This has been driving me crazy and is something that should be easy, but I never touched vba before, so...

I have a for loop iterating on a row searching for matching occurrences, I know the loop is working because I can get an accurate count of the number of matching occurrences. Essentially "if month = month then counter=counter+1"

Whenever the loop finds a matching occurrence I need it to copy a specific cell (let's say AA22) to another worksheet, but I cant get it to work, it keeps throwing error codes with super broad and vague descriptions. I've tried a few of the solutions here and a few on other forums, nothing works correctly. Also, it seems every solution works with ranges, I need one that copies cells one by one.
Here's my code:

```
Dim chomonth As Integer

   chomonth = InputBox("Insira o mes ", "Inserir dados")

   Dim counter As Integer
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim rw As Range
   Dim cell As Range

   Set rng = Range("S3:S9999")

    For Each rw In rng.Rows

        If month(rw.row) = chomonth Then
          //Code that copies AArw to worksheet 2 goes here

        counter = counter + 1



        End If

    Next rw

    MsgBox ("Numero de entradas:" & Count)
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you showed us the errors the code throws up and the line that is causing it

Comment: I've tried a few lines, but this one seemed the most logical throws error 1004   Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, counter).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(27, rw).Value

Comment: You are not setting the `counter` before copying to another sheet, And `rw` represents a `Range` so doing `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(27, rw).Value` will throw an error

Comment: Note: Use `Long` instead of `Integer` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle, and there is no benefit at all in using `Integer` over `Long` in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If month(rw.row) = chomonth Then

    counter = counter + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw.row, 27).Value

End If
```